# InstrumentTest Resources with Android + Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-resources, android-gradle-plugin

I need to test a custom Adapter which uses a TypedArray from which to create the data. I want to write an instrument test for it (i.e. AndroidTestCase) which of course needs its own test resources.

After setting up the instrumentTest subfolder with the following structure:

```
/ instrumentTest
  - src
  / res
    - drawable
    - layout
      # layouts for the tests
    - values
      # resource values where the TypedArray exists
```

Initially Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA 13) do not recognize the R references (under `PACKAGE_NAME.test.R`, but after I run `assembleTest` they get recognized all right. When I do a `connectedInstrumentTest` the tests fail because of this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x7f040000
    at android.content.res.Resources.obtainTypedArray(Resources.java:509)
```

The resource it is failing at is under `PACKAGE_NAME.test.R`.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `AndroidTestCase`. The context it provides appears not to be actually usable. Changing to `InstrumentationTestCase` and getting the resources from

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources()
```

Seems to work just fine.